# Julia: Standard method to write data to ::Cmd

Tags: command-line, io, julia

I'm struggling to find a simple way to read data from `arecord`, and then after some processing send it to `aplay` using Julia. I've figured out how to use pipelines to directly send data over:

```
run(pipeline(`arecord -d 3`, `aplay`))    # Same as: arecord -d 3 | aplay
```

I've also figured out how to obtain data:

```
data = read(`arecord -d 3`)
```

However, the simple task of outputting `data` to `aplay` has eluded me, which got me thinking of how, in general, one would go about taking some data `d` and throwing it into some `::Cmd` (or at least converting some `::Cmd` into an `::IOStream`) variable in Julia. Also, what would the differences be between a 1 off stream (like the above for reading audio data) and a continuous stream (which would only stop after being told to close).

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

EDIT: `arecord` and `aplay` are standard linux terminal commands to record and play audio. `arecord -d 3` generates a simple vector of 8bit values, sampling at 8kHz.

To be clear, I'm asking:

- What is the standard way of reading data from a `::Cmd` as a continuous data stream into a vector (e.g. reading from a never-ending file).
- What is the standard way of writing a vector of data into a `::Cmd` as either a 1 off instance or as a continuous stream of data (e.g. writing to a file once verses continually appending it).
- This is **NOT** file specific because writing to `aplay`, a standard `::Cmd` variable which works in the pipeline example above, does not work when just trying to pass it some data using either the `pipeline` or `write` functions (or at least I have been unsuccessful in doing so).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more better? What is `arecord` and `aplay` here? and what is given as input along with what is that you are missing.

Comment: @RahulLakhanpal updated question to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading and processing `data`. Try

```
open(`aplay`,"w",STDOUT) do stdin
    write(stdin, data)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that, audio works as expected. I'm not sure why this works as a loop as opposed to `stdin = open('aplay',"w",STDOUT)` followed by `write(stdin, data)` (swapping ' with backtick as needed). Is there any reasoning behind this that might help me not get confused again in the future?

Comment: @user3303504 Regarding the other method of writing this (without `do` syntax) I think it should work. But haven't tested with `aplay` since it doesn't work in my chrooted Julia environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case (which lead to a lot of my confusion). The documentation isn't too great on this stuff at the moment either which isn't helping =( I've discovered that when you try to tell aplay what sampling frequency and data type to use that it breaks things again X( and reading data for any type other than 8bit makes it harder to read all the data in 1 go (no file size functions I could find).

Comment: @user3303504 Can you add the specific `arecord` and `aplay` commands you are using (forget about the processing for a bit).